# Como crear una lista a partir de las entradas en java?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo que crear una matriz que agregue cierta cantidad de entradas. Por ejemplo;

La primera entrada es la cantidad de arreglos que va a tener mi matriz, en este ejemplo 2. Es decir que mi matriz tendrá dos arreglos.

Entonces, por ende mi programa debe recibir dos entradas, las cuales son:

Mallorquin 0 Barranquilla 30
Magdalena 1 Barranquilla 45.3

Necesito que el programa me agregue la cantidad de arreglos a recibir y que me los muestre por consola. Sucede que si agrega los venctores pero cuando imprime la matriz me aparece los siguiente `[[Ljava.lang.String;@3d494fbf, [Ljava.lang.String;@1ddc4ec2]`:

```
Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cantidadCuerpos = data.nextInt();
    
    ArrayList info = new ArrayList();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadCuerpos; i++){
        Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] entrada = datos.nextLine().split(" ");
        info.add(entrada);
    }
   System.out.println(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar el `ArrayList` con el tipo de dato que se almacenara dentro, como sera arrays de tipo `String` la declaración debe ser la siguiente

```
ArrayList<String[]>info = new ArrayList<>();
```

para imprimir el o lo arrays guardados en el `ArrayList` debes iterar `info` y apoyarte del método `toString()`

```
 for (int i=0;i<info.size();i++ ) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(info.get(i)));
 }
```

si estas puesto a usar lambda podes imprimir los datos de la siguiente manera

```
info.forEach((p) -> Arrays.stream(p).forEach(o ->System.out.println(o)));
```

o usar method reference,todo ello usando java 8+

```
info.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```